# very slow in sending emails

Tags: scheduled-job, mail

I am trying to send an email to around 4 thousand contacts but it took one day to send it to 500.
I tried to go on "scheduled jobs" and "execute the job now" but it says error and I don't see improvements.

As suggested in an other question I also went on Civimail settings and I put 100 as Mailer Batch Limit, but nothing changed.

Hope you can help me.
Many thanks!

Comment: Do you know if you have any limits set with your mail provider on how many emails can go out an hour?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely your ISP throttling your output. When we were with 1&1 it took 2 days to send 3500 email. Now we are with AWS it takes 50 minutes. You might be able to apply to your ISP to raise your limits.